# i want to merge a substring to another matching string in an Arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist, merge, substring

**I want to merge a part of a string to another matching string in an Arraylist**

for example

***INPUT***

20 E 87th Street/New York//123

20 e 87th street/new york/USA/123

in the above input the line is same except that it is **missing one substring USA,**

So i want to merge that USA to that line

***and the output should be***

20 E 87th Street/New York/USA/123

20 e 87th street/new york/USA/123

code that i have

```
   for (String address : array_adrress)
{
 String str1="";
 String new_country="";
 String new_string="";
 int pos_city=address.indexOf("/");
 int pos_zip=address.lastIndexOf("/");
 String zip=address.substring(pos_zip);
 String address=address.substring(pos_city,pos_zip);         
 int pos_country=address.lastIndexOf("/");
 String country=address.substring(pos_country+1);
 if(country.isEmpty())
 {
     str1=check_example(address);
 }
 if(str1!="")
 {
     new_country=str1;
 }
 else new_country=country;
if(address.indexOf("//")>0)
{
 new_string=address.substring(0,address.indexOf("//")+2);
}
else
new_string=address.substring(0,n5);
 new_string=new_string+new_country+zip;
}   
   public static String check_example(String s)throws IOException
   {
  for (String address : array_adrress)
  { 
 if(address.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))
 {  
 String str1="";
 String new_country="";
 String new_string="";
 int pos_city=address.indexOf("/");
 int pos_zip=address.lastIndexOf("/");
 String zip=address.substring(pos_zip);
 String address=address.substring(pos_city,pos_zip);         
 int pos_country=address.lastIndexOf("/");
 String country=address.substring(pos_country+1);
 if(!country.isEmpty())
 {           
    return country; 
 }
 }

}
 return "";
```

}

Comment: Then please share the code you created so far. This site is not a place where you drop your requirements and other do the coding for you. We expect you to show your efforts and to exactly point out where you are stuck.

Comment: can you please share the code you tried, we are here to fix bugs in your code not to code at your home

Answer (score 0):

cut it with substring() and concatenate the string

substring one = 20 E 87th Street/New York/ +"USA"+ substring two /123